# how to change a length of an wav audio file to fit a fixed length by squeezing it

Tags: python, audio, wav

I have a set of audio file with length varying between 2 to 3 secs.

How can i change the length or the duration of these audio files to fit to 2 seconds. but i cannot crop the data. need to squeeze the data and manipulate the speed of audio instead of cropping.

[image]

for example the minimum length of this file is about 2.3s after cropping. i still need to make it exactly 2 seconds without.

i am trying to use these data in bio matrix authentication. so this process should not damage any important features of the data. is it possible to change it in a way it is exactly as if the person spoke a listen faster.

Any reference how i can do this?

Comment: Actually, technically the wav format has no duration. It is just a series of samples. In order to affect the duration, you just need to change the sample rate.

Comment: @fdcpp thanks for the answer, so how can i down sample this data for it to have the same sample rate when it is 2s

Comment: I‘ve expanded on it in an answer below, though I did make the assumption that you were dealing with wav files. If you are dealing with some lossy compressed format, you would need to convert to back to PCM and then re-encode.

Comment: **if** you are just dealing with audio in audacity, you could simply [change the speed](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/change_speed.html)

Answer (score 0):

1 option:

Silence removal in speech signals, this will reduce the size and the duration of the speech file.

You can use mathlab tool to do this , Here are some reference :

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28826-silence-removal-in-speech-signals?focused=c9fdfa40-65ab-e9fe-13b9-d9d3efb80fa8&tab=function

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/57485-remove-silence-from-the-speech-signal-for-accurate-recognition

you can search for any other Audio editor that does this.